# Why does ternary operator throw NPE in case of auto-unboxing?

Tags: java

In the following test, the `getDummyAge()` method should not be evaluated, because `testage` variable is always `null`.

```
public class IntegerTest {
    @Test
    public void intergerTestFailure() {
        Integer testage = null;
        Integer age = (testage != null) ? getDummyAge() : testage;
    }

    private int getDummyAge() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Though this throws an exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   my.IntegerTest.intergerTestFailure(IntegerTest.java:18)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

Is this a jdk bug?

Comment: Numeric 2nd and 3rd operands undergo binary numeric promotion, so an `Integer` will be unboxed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Integer age = (testage != null) ? getDummyAge() : testage;
```

is equivalent to

```
Integer age = Integer.valueOf((testage != null) ? getDummyAge().intValue() : testage);
```

because numeric second and third operands of differing types undergo binary numeric promotion; the result of the conditional operator is `int`, which then has to be boxed back to `Integer` for the assignment.

This is as specified.

If you want to avoid the NPE, box the `int` explicitly:

```
Integer age = (testage != null) ? Integer.valueOf(getDummyAge()) : testage;
```

Boxed numerical operands of the same type are not unboxed.