# How to convert varying number type to Double?

Tags: java, casting, double

A `Hashmap` contains a key with a value that can be an `Integer` or `Double`.

This works if the value is of type `Double` but fails for type `Integer`:

```
Double value = (Double) locationMap.get("key");
```

Unfortunately I cannot seem to control the type, as it is JSON data transmitted from a server. Apparently, even if the number is of type `double` server-side (Javascript) before transmission, but does not have decimal digits, it will be interpreted as `Integer` somewhere along the line on the client side (Java).

What is the shortest way to account for a possible `Integer` value and cast it to `Double`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you know it's a `Number` (e.g. you tested with `instanceof` first):

```
Double value = ((Number) locationMap.get("key")).doubleValue();
```

This is inefficient if the number is already a `Double`. You may want to define a method to handle that specially:

```
// Doesn't handle null.
Double toDouble(Number n) {
  return (n instanceof Double) ? (Double) n : Double.valueOf(n.doubleValue());
}
```

The `Double.valueOf` looks redundant, but is necessary if using a conditional expression to avoid unboxing of the second operand ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55342531/3788176)).

Comment: Works perfectly! I think you just broke the record for time to correct answer. For me at least ;)